# dynamic memory allocation, heap, indirection, NULL

Tags: c++, heap-memory, indirection

I was trying to guarantee that memory I allocated dynamically is pointing nowhere.

I tried the following

```
template<typename T>
[...something here...]
T *mem = new T[size];

for ( int i=0; i<size; i++ )
{
    (mem+i) = NULL;
}  
[...something else there...]
```

Just as one could write

```
int *pInt = new int;
pInt = NULL;
```

But it that doesn't work because in the upper example `mem` isn't an "lvalue"?

Why does this only appear to be the case if I allocate dynamically more the one type-specific memory on the heap?

In addition one strange thing happens if I use a template-function, because it seems to be legal to write

```
template<typename T>
[...something here...]
T mem = new T[size];

for ( int i=0; i<size; i++ )
{
    *(mem+i) = NULL;

    /* or the equivalent
    mem[i] = NULL;
    */
}  
[...something else there...]
```

How can it be possible to assign `NULL` (which is basically the `int` value 0) to a variable or object that could be basically anything? It might be an `int` variable, fine, it would work. But what if I called the template function with `std::string`. It shouldn't work at all, right? So why does it appear to be legal to write something like this?

Is it the freedom to program generic but also the responsibility to watch out, not to invoke some generic function with the wrong type?

Comment: You cannot assign NULL to everything so what you are attempting to do is impossible. Perhaps you could explain the underlying problem.

Comment: Post real code.  The template makes no sense (try substituting `int` for `T`)

Comment: You can assign 0 to a variable even if its type is not `int` because of implicit conversions.

Comment: Maybe you mean: T *mem = new T[size]; ?

Comment: Your code only makes sense if `T` is a pointer type.

Comment: Image that there's a pointer to a class, dynamically allocated to 5 elements. Now i would like to make the 2'nd and the 3'rd element to point nowhere, lets say, initialize them. The objects they were pointing to, lets say they don't matter at the moment. But i dont want to use delete, because the memory size, wich has been allocated, should remain allocated, in order to be able to assign some other objects to the nulled pointers.

Comment: `new()` will automatically initialize all elements in the allocated array with the default constructor for that type. Just make sure you properly define one - don't go messing around with re-initializing it all after `new()` returns...

Answer (score 1):

> But it that doesn't work because in the upper example "mem" isn't an "lvalue"?

Indeed, you're trying to reassign the temporary pointer `mem+i`; that doesn't make sense. Presumably, you want to set the array member (`mem[i]` or `*(mem+i)`), to something; although probably not to `NULL` unless `T` is supposed to be a pointer type.

In the example with a single object, you're reassigning the only pointer to the allocated object; so you then have no way to use or delete the object.

> How can it be possible to assign NULL ( wich is basically the int value 0 ) to an variable or object that could be basically anything?

Because, before C++11, the only valid null pointer constants (and therefore the only valid expansions of the `NULL` macro) were zero-valued integer constants; so the code expands to something like

```
*(mem+i) = 0;
```

which is valid for many types. These days, `NULL` might (or might not) expand to `nullptr`, in which case it will only be valid for pointer types.

> But what if i called the template function with std::string. It shouldn't work at all, right ?

`std::string` has a constructor and assignment operator taking a pointer to a C-style string, to allow for example

```
std::string hello = "Hello, world!";
```

These can also take a null pointer, giving undefined behavoiur.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
for ( int i=0; i<size; i++ )
{
  (mem+i) = NULL;
}
```

In this case `(mem+i)` is an temporary result and is called rvalue. rvalues are temporary you must not assign them a value. You can only assign a value to an lvalue. (BTW I think this is not what you want to do: I guess you want to change the memory to which the pointer shows and not the address value stored in the pointer)

```
for ( int i=0; i<size; i++ )
{
  mem[i] = NULL;
 *(mem+i) = NULL;
}
```

In this case also temporary results are computed (in both cases `mem+i`) but the are used to address the correct memory. Thus in both cases the memory which is pointed to is a lvalue.

If you use templates you must keep in mind that these are templates ;-)
A template code is never compiled if the template is not used anywhere. And if it is used it depends on what kind of variable/class you use as template argument.

You can write this code:

```
template<typename T>
void func( T a)
{
  a.foo = "bar";
  a.my_func( 3.14);
}
```

This code looks strang, but it will compile for each `a` which is of any structure or class with a member variable/object `foo` that  can be assigned a `const char`and a member function or function pointer or object with overloaded `operator ()` with the name `my_func`.

Comment: Well, i am trying to make a function that allocates memory to a pointer, passed as an argument. The allocation size is also passed as an int value. 

I wanted to make sure, that the temporary memory points nowhere and only "holds" the type-specific sized memory space.

That was at least my thougt.

Comment: What about the following code:  
  
`template <class T>  
  
int get_mem( T* & ptr, int len)  
  
{  
  
  try{ptr=new T[len];}  
  
  catch(...) {ptr=nullptr; return 1;}  
  
  for (int i=0; i<len; i++)  
  
    ptr[i] = 0;  
  
  return 0;  
  
}`  
  
This code should work if `T` is a pointer or if it is an int or a double.